# Rails naming convention for lengthy table name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, naming-conventions

Master tables: `assortments`, `companies`, `submission_types`

Mapped assortments with company in `assortments_companies`.

Mapped submission_types with company in `companies_submission_types`.

Now I want to map `assortments_companies` with `companies_submission_types`.

Is it good to have a table name with rails convention like  this `assortments_companies_companies_submission_types`? So my model name will be `AssortmentCompanyCompanySubmissionType`.

Is there any better approach to over come the lengthy name?

Comment: I think you should get an other name, then use `has_many` associations for `companies_submission_types` and `assortments_companies`

Answer (score 1):

Very often many-to-many join tables between entities are really *events*, with extra attributes you want to track. Whenever I have a join table, I consider whether I can name it something more meaningful than just `foos_bars`. For instance between `accounts` and `plans` you don't have `accounts_plans` but `subscriptions`.

It is hard to suggest specific names without knowing your domain, but perhaps `assortment_submissions` or even just `submissions`?

Comment: I will consider it for my current situation :)